# Draw a number in status bar like WeatherBug for android

Tags: android

In case you're unfamiliar, WeatherBug has a temperature display in the status bar that will say something like "38". I'm new to android programming, but from what I can see, if you want to put something in the status bar, you have to have a drawable.

Now I know they could've made a 100+ branch if statement, but since that's unlikely, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the cuff...

Step #1: Create your individual temperature drawables.

Step #2: Create [a `LevelListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) that references those individual temperature drawables, for levels corresponding with the temperature.

Step #3: [Use `setSmallIcon(int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon%28int,%20int%29) to point to your `LevelListDrawable` and the desired level.